# How to fix undefined variable problem in php?

Tags: php, php-7.2

I have a `php code` in which I am getting the error message `Notice: Undefined variable: c at LineA`

```
<?php echo HelloWorld($a, $b = 6, $c); ?>  // LineA
```

The function definition is shown below:

```
function HelloWorld($a,$b = 0,$c = [],$max_text_length = 50) {


}
```

In order to fix the problem, I have added LineB above LineA.

```
<?php $c=[] ?> // LineB
<?php echo HelloWorld($a, $b = 6, $c); ?>  // LineA
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering if there any way I can fix the undefined variable problem for that paritcular case.

Comment: `I am wondering if there any way I can fix the undefined variable problem for that paritcular case.` Yeah. Define `$c`.

Comment: Remove $c if you do not intend to define it. `<?php echo HelloWorld($a, 6); ?>`

Comment: you can use an if-else block to see is variable `$c` is set or not for calling the `HelloWorld` function with or without variable `$c` like  `if (isset($c))` then call `HelloWorld($a, $b = 6, $c)` else `HelloWorld($a, $b = 6)`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to change the `$c` variable don't do it you have already set a default value in the function.

```
HelloWorld(1, 6); 
function HelloWorld($a, $b = 0,$c = [],$max_text_length = 50) {
    print_r([$a, $b,$c,$max_text_length]); 
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1  //<-- $a
    [1] => 6  //<-- $b
    [2] => Array //<-- $c
        (
        )

    [3] => 50 //<-- $max_text_length
)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to modify the function call, you can try this:

```
<?php echo HelloWorld($a, $b = 6, $c ?? []); ?>
```

So that if `$c` is not already defined of if it is `null`, an empty array (`[]`) will be used. If `$c` is set, it will be used. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

Comment: What's the point of having a function with the default `array` parameter if you then use a `null`?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini You may also use `$c ?? []`. I don't think that there is a big difference. But I get your point and I will update the answer.

Comment: I think the best option is use a simple `if`, so use or not the variable base of the result.